# Django: detect what models was used in query

Tags: python, django, django-orm, python-decorators

**TL;DR:** Need to know what models was used in queries executed in some block of code

I have self-made caching system that has ability to automatically drop cache when specific models get saved.

The usage is (example in Django Rest framework API viewset):

```py
class UsersViewSet(ListModelMixin)
    model = User
    queryset = User.objects

    # Here cache decorator goes
    @cache_view(models_to_drop_cache=[User, UserProfile, UserPhone])
    def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        # calling the real viewset method
        return super().list(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Now when any of models `[User, UserProfile, UserPhone]` change, cache on that view would be dropped (it's achieved by using signal receiver of model save signal).

**The problem is**: sometimes not all models got written to the list (somebody forgot to) and cache not being dropped when it should.

I want to add some `debug` argument to method cache_view so in debug mode decorator gather information about models that was used in the decorated method and output the list.

I've tried to look for model signals but didn't succeeded. It seems like I need to monkey-patch Django's query builder to check for table names in resulting SQL code that got executed.

Maybe there is more straightforward method?